# What card sleeves should I get for Cards Against Humanity?

Tags: storage, cards-against-humanity

They measure 63mm wide by 88mm tall.

The base set has 550 cards (460 White cards and 90 Black cards).

The expansion has 100 cards (80 White cards and 20 Black cards) plus 12 blank cards (8 white, 4 black).

---

For the uninitiated, [Cards Against Humanity](http://cardsagainsthumanity.com/).

[image: Cards Against Humanity]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I bought ultra pro black sleeves and ultrapro white sleeves (700) for my cards against humanity [I have both expansions].

Using both colors helps keep cards distinct. Also, since we usually play around drinks it helps ensure that they stay protected/away from sticky surfaces.

Additionally useful, is that the write your own blank cards stay in tact (i used a sharpie and the text started to smudge off).

Answer (score 14):

**None**, but I am betting this was a trick question. The cards dimensions are fairly close to the standard dimensions of a Magic: the Gathering card. The cheapest card sleeves you could buy are the aptly named **penny sleeves**. These sleeves will run you on average $0.01 US. Since Cards Against Humanity runs 550 cards in the base set, you would be spending $5.50 to sleeve the cards, slightly over 20% the cost of buying a complete replacement of the entire game. I suppose if you buy online, and sufficient quantity, you might be able to reduce the cost of the sleeves by 20%-30%.

Sleeving will increase the thickness, so it will not fit in the original box. There are other issues with sleeving. Sleeves of any sort make shuffling more difficult. Penny sleeves are also notoriously slippery because they don't have textured backs (Like Dragon Shield or other high quality sleeves). High quality sleeves would cost you more than the original game itself to sleeve. Games are meant to be played, and this game wouldn't suffer much from having marked cards. As an Apples-to-Apples clone, the only danger of marked cards is that the judge might know which card you or another player through in the pot. This problem can be eliminated by having the judge close his eyes, look away, and having someone else shuffle the cards before giving them to the judge (we usually do this anyway to prevent the top card being the card from the person who decided last).

I would recommend against sleeving.

Comment: Just to be clear, your recommendation against sleeving is mainly because of cost? If so, that makes a lot of sense. But what if I have a first edition set? Buy another set and not play with the original?

Comment: First Edition or otherwise wouldn't make much of a difference in this case. The cards themselves don't currently have much value, and will not likely in the future. Buying another set will double your costs. Why do you want to preserve the 1st Edition copy in the first place?

Comment: I like to collect cards haha. And I'd like my collected cards to be in good condition. It's not about preserving value as much as about preserving aesthetic.

Comment: I find that sleeves actually make it much easier to "mash shuffle" your cards (cut your deck and then mush the two halves together). Also, sleeves can be a good thing even for party games if you tend to play around food.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer considering the style of play of the game, but a small thought in defense of sleeving them in regular magic sleeves: Yes, a full set of sleeves will probably run you $25-40 but as those sleeves get damaged/split through wear you can replace them with identical sleeves. If you play this game a lot (and drinking or messy people are involved) the chances of having marked cards goes up, and it becomes a non-zero chance that the same card could get damaged twice or more... you don't want to buy a third set, but another pack of 50 sleeves'd only be a couple bucks.

Answer (score 2):

I also bought Ultra Pro sleeves for my deck, in black. I made a fusion deck with the main set, 1st & 2nd edition, plus selected Apples to Apples cards.  Ended up with almost 850 cards in total, so I picked up a cardboard deck box from a game shop for less than two bucks.

With shipping, I was able to get them for $0.05/each on Ebay. Well worth the amusement of a durable, well used and (pseudo) hacked set.